# Form Validation Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a simple Form Validation so the Form shows errors

This is my code:

```
function postregform(frm) {

 var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;   

  if (frm.name.value='') { 
     $('#error-container2').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);   
       $('#error-container3').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container4').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container5').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container6').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
    $('#error-container7').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
   $('#error-container').delay.(200).animate({'top' : '4px'}, 400);
      $('#error-container').delay(3700).animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 400);
   return false; 
  }
  if (frm.email.value=='') { 
    $('#error-container').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);   
       $('#error-container3').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container4').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container5').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container6').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
    $('#error-container7').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
    $('#error-container2').delay(200).animate({'top' : '4px'}, 400);
      $('#error-container2').delay(3700).animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 400);           
    return false;

                            }
   if (! emailPattern.test(frm.email.value)) { 
    $('#error-container').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);   
       $('#error-container2').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container4').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container5').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container6').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
    $('#error-container7').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100); 
     $('#error-container3').delay(200).animate({'top' : '4px'}, 400);
      $('#error-container3').delay(3700).animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 400);                    
     return false;
                                               }
       if (frm.textarea.value=='') { 
         $('#error-container').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);   
       $('#error-container3').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container2').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container5').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container6').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
    $('#error-container7').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
         $('#error-container4')delay(200).animate({'top' : '4px'}, 400);
      $('#error-container4').delay(3700).animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 400);           
    return false;
                           }
        if (frm.textarea.value.length < 10) { 
          $('#error-container').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);   
       $('#error-container3').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container4').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container2').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container6').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
    $('#error-container7').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
         $('#error-container5').animate({'top' : '4px'}, 400);
      $('#error-container5').delay(3700).animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 400);           
    return false;
                          }
       if (frm.textarea1.value.length < 10) { 
         $('#error-container').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);   
       $('#error-container3').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container4').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container5').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container2').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
    $('#error-container7').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
         $('#error-container6').delay(200).animate({'top' : '4px'}, 400);
      $('#error-container6').delay(3700).animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 400);           
    return false;
                           }
       if (frm.tooln.value.length < 10) { 
        $('#error-container').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);   
       $('#error-container3').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container4').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container5').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
        $('#error-container6').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
    $('#error-container2').animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 100);
         $('#error-container7').delay(200).animate({'top' : '4px'}, 400);
      $('#error-container7').delay(3700).animate({'top' : '-70px'}, 400);           
    return false;
                           }
    }
```

And I got the onSubmit="return postregform(this)" setup in the form tag and it worked at first but now it is not. Can someone please help me?

Thanks,
Shawn

Comment: Any reason you're not using one of the many libraries already available for validation? No sense in trying to reinvent the wheel here. There are so many JS libraries that already do all types of form validation that are very simple to use, performant, and extensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be at least one of the problems `if (frm.name.value='') {` (hint just one **=** instead of two **==**) but boy I only see noodles when I look at your code :)

There has to be a way to make the code look cleaner and more readable :)

Comment: Well, i think its easy to read for me but thanks for the suggestion but the DOWN was not nessesary

Comment: Yea, well im still learning JQuery right now and thats the only way i thought of it but once I get this to work then i can make another JQUery fn using:

jquery.fn.validate = //code here
Then I could simply do:
$('#id').validate()

Comment: "DOWN"? If you are referencing to downvoting I don't do that :)